# GIT Jenkins Plugin cloning instead of pulling

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using the GIT Jenkins Plugin. It clones the git repository instead of running git pull.

How can I force it to run git pull?

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@git.corp.example.com:example/example.git
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are clearing out your workspace between builds, or if your build is on a node that doesn't have the source code already, the plugin will clone the repo; because, there is nothing to pull.

I suggest finding your workspace within your Jenkins slave , prior to running your Jenkins job.  I imagine you'll find it lacks source code.  If it has source code, check that you're not cleaning your workspace or otherwise forcing the clone.

Note that in a multi-slave environment, any Jenkins slave could be the one that does the build.  Also, if you are building on the Master node, I suggest that you reconfigure to not do that; as the workflows building on the master node are subtly different than building on remote slaves (and debugging between the two is always problematic).